# GROUP BY one column to find MAX, but keep value from another column - SQL

Tags: sql

```
 A   |   B   |   num
----------------------
123      1       2
123      10      5
```

Result:

```
 A   |   B   |   max_num
-------------------------
123      10      5
```

Let's say the table name is tab, currently I have

```
SELECT T.A, MAX(T.num) AS max_num
FROM tab T
GROUP BY T.A
```

However, the result will not contain the column B.

```
SELECT T.A, T.B... GROUP BY T.A, T.B
```

Will also not give the desired result, since max is found based on the A,B pair.

How can I choose the max of num grouped by only A, but then keep the value of B for the max row that is chosen?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Answer (score 2):

1.Select Max num from table

2.Just filter of IN Clause

```
select * from Mytable where
num in(
select TOP 1 MAX(num)
from mytab
group by colA)
```

or

For SQL SERVER

You can Use Window function for single Max using `ROW_NUMBER ()`

```
select * from (
select ROW_NUMBER () OVER (ORDER BY num desc) rn,*
from tab
)d where d.rn=1
```

Comment: That doesn't work if you have some other value in column A where `num` has also the value of `select MAX(num)
from mytab
group by colA` like `456 | 5 |10`

Comment: This would work. The problem is the outer query. See the [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9054bf/1) And also TOP 1 does not work on all DBMS. It is not clear which DBMS OP is using.

Comment: @Jens yes but Questioner not mentioned :)

Comment: Thanks for the replies.
What if the table comes from a subquery?

Answer (score 1):

This should do the job:

```
Select t1.A, T1.B,T1.num from tab t1 where (T1.A,T1.num) in (
   SELECT T.A, MAX(T.num) AS max_num
   FROM tab T
   GROUP BY T.A)
```

Selection the Record where num equals the `max(num)`

See the [SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9054b/5)

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean you want the whole rows where c = the max(c) value for each a? This one will give both rows if it's a tie:

```
select a, b, c
from t as t1
where c = (select max(c) from t t2
           where t1.a = t2.a)
```